# Implications of comma separated var in JS

Tags: javascript

We've found an interesting behavior in one of our variable definitions.

We have the following

```
var productId = data.data.productId,
    productCartQty    = data.data.currentQty,
    $modules          = $(".module-grocery-product[data-product-id='"+productId+"']"),
    $form             = $modules.find(".form-product"),
    $inputs           = $form.find('input.cart-change-qty'),
    $inputPrettyValue = $form.find('.input-qty-pretty-value');
```

The interesting behaviour is with $modules it throws an error that productId is not defined.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before and can explain why? 'use strict' is enabled.

This then goes through r.js minification and Uglify2 compression.

Comment: is your `data.data.productId` defined? If you'll have `var productId = data.data.productId; var $modules = ...`, does the error disappear?

Comment: Based on http://jsbin.com/kiciganemo/edit?js,console, looks like your `data.data.productId` isn't defined

Comment: We checked and it does have a value, this is inside of an ajax done return

Comment: @JamesWilkinson, if your ajax return completes after you are defining your variables, it won't work. can you share the code of your ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

If data.data.productId does not point to anything (is undefined) then var productId will also be undefined.

Make sure that property is defined before you bind productId to it.